# ¿Cómo convertir un campo image de SQL Server a texto plano?

Tags: sql-server, imagen, blob, cast, bitconverter

Tengo una tabla en SQL Server con un campo de tipo image en el cual se almacena el contenido de una matríz, que se visualiza en un sistema del cual no tengo acceso al código fuente, pero si a la base de datos, necesito obtener el contenido de dicho campo en texto plano y así mismo poder editarlo.

He probado decodificar en https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.html y obtengo la deocodificacion del texto, pero las cantidades aparecen con caracteres extraños. He probado con funciones de SQL como Convert y cast pero estas solo me detectan la primera palabra del registro e ignoran el contenido posterior.

```
select cast(cast(CAMPO as varbinary(max)) as varchar(max)) from  tabla;

select convert (varchar(max) , convert (varbinary (max) ,CAMPO)) from  tabla;
```

El contenido de la matriz es algo similar a:

DIAS  | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 15.00
DVAC | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00
DVIG | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00

Cuando decodifico de Hexadecimal a ASCII obtengo:

```
DIASffffDVACDVIGffff
```

y cuando pruebo en SQL server con las funciones antes mencionadas solo obtengo:

```
DIAS
```

Comment: Talvez te puede servir esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880137/convert-image-datatype-into-varchar-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: corresponde a las pruebas realizadas que indico en la sección de código sql, pero sólo me muestra lo correspondiente al primer registro de la matriz y me ignora lo demás